# how to change the font color in jquery

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

i want to change the font color of `html(username + ' is already exist. Please try another one');`
but i don't know how to change this.

```
function check_availability(){  

    //get the username  
    var username = $('#username').val();  

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>loginFunction/checkUsername", { username: username },  
        function(result){  
            //if the result is 1  
            if(result == 1){  
                //show that the username is available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');  
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is already exist. Please try another one');  
            }  
    });
```

Comment: You may wrap it with span and style that span.

Comment: `$('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is already exist. Please try another one').css( "color", "red" );` http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: U didn't respond on any answer yet

Answer (score 1):

Try with `css` -

```
$('#username_availability_result')
.css('color', 'red')
.html(username + ' is already exist. Please try another one');
```

Comment: `font-color` is not a valid css property

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#username_availability_result').css("color","red");
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it up in a span tag.

```
function check_availability(){  

    //get the username  
    var username = $('#username').val();  

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>loginFunction/checkUsername", { username: username },  
        function(result){  
            //if the result is 1  
            if(result == 1){  
                //show that the username is available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');  
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html('<span style="color:#f00;">' + username + ' is already exist. Please try another one</span>');
            }  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `jQuery attr` :

```
$('#username_availability_result').attr('style','color:red');
$('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is already exist. Please try another one');
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
 function check_availability(){  

        //get the username  
        var username = $('#username').val();  

        //use ajax to run the check  
        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>loginFunction/checkUsername", { username: username },  
            function(result){  
                //if the result is 1  
                if(result == 1){  
                    //show that the username is available  
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');  

    $('#username_availability_result').css({
      'color': 'black'
    });
                }else{  
                    //show that the username is NOT available  
                    $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is already exist. Please try another one');  

    $('#username_availability_result').css({
      'color': 'red'
    });
                }  
        });
```